# What are scalar types in GraphQL

Tags: graphql

From their docs, it says:

> The leaf values of any request and input values to arguments are Scalars (or Enums) and are defined with a name and a series of serialization functions used to ensure validity

but I am unable to comprehend that definition. From the answer to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57250581/how-to-make-custom-type-with-definite-value-in-graphql/57251169#57251169), I think scalars are associated with enums. Can someone break down in simpler terms what do GraphQL scalar types do and when to use scalar types as opposed to enum types?

Answer (score 11):

Scalars are equivalent to [primitive data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_data_type) in a programming language. In GraphQL, there are five built-in scalar types:

- **Boolean**, true or false
- **Int**, a signed 32‐bit numeric non‐fractional value
- **Float**, a signed double‐precision fractional values
- **String**, a sequence of UTF‐8 characters
- **ID**, a unique identifier

A scalar simply represents a single value and are the basic building blocks of your schema. This is in comparison to object types, which represent a collection of values. An object type has fields, and each field has a type which may be a scalar or an object type itself. If the field's type is an object, that object will have fields that are also scalars or other objects, and so on. In this way we end up with a *tree-like* structure in both our schema and the queries made against it.

```
query {       # <- The "root" of the tree
  movies {
    actors {
      name    # <- A "leaf" on the tree
    }
    crew {
      name    # <- Another "leaf"
    }
  }  
}
```

Enums are similar to scalars, in that an enum represents a single, concrete value. However, each enum type is defined explicitly in the schema (there are no "built-in" enums) and its definition must include a set of values that the enum type can be. For example, we might create an enum like:

```
enum Animal {
  Cat
  Dog
  Bird
}
```

A field that returns an `Animal` will still have a single value, like a scalar, but that value will be either "Cat", "Dog" or "Bird" -- no other values are allowed.

A *leaf type* is a term that encompasses *both* scalars and enums. Leaf types represent the leaves or terminating points in our tree-like queries and their responses.

When a field returns an object type (like `movies`, `actors`, or `crew` in the above example), we *have* to tell GraphQL which of the object type's fields we want to query. This *selection* of fields is called a *selection set* and is wrapped by curly brackets. In our example, `name` is the selection set for the `crew` field, `crew` and `actors` are the selection set for the `movies` field, and even the `movies` field is part of the selection set for the query root type.

The important thing to notice here is that **leaf types do not have fields, so any field that returns a leaf type will not have a selection set**.

For more information, you can check out the official [spec](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018).